# Open Google Scene Viewer from Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, webview, sceneform, android-augmented-reality, model-viewer

i'm trying to open the follow  script from a webview in Flutter :

```
<model-viewer src="https://dashboard.impiattalo.com/storage/app/public/259/bistecca.gltf" alt="A 3D model of an astronaut" auto-rotate camera-controls ar ar-modes="web-xr scene-viewer quick-look fallback"  ar-scale="auto"></model-viewer>
```

When i try to open the ar from Chrome, it works quite well, in flutter web view it doesn't work and it give me this error.

[Error Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paLsN.jpg)

This is the code that i use :

```
                    child: WebView(
                            initialUrl:
                                'https://dashboard.impiattalo.com/3DViewer?url=${_con.food?.fbx_model?.url}',
                            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                            gestureRecognizers: <
                                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                              Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                                () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onUpdate = (_) {},
                              )
                            },
                          ),
```

and this is the pubspec :

```
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.20+2
```

Do you have any suggestion? thanks in advice

Comment: See https://github.com/drydart/model_viewer.dart/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered relates to the known issue [google/model-viewer#743](https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/743): it is not possible to launch Google's Scene Viewer from an Android WebView sans a workaround.

To make this work with Flutter, you can just use the [Model Viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/model_viewer) package for Flutter, which embeds Google's `<model-viewer>` web component and incorporates the necessary workaround (see [drydart/model_viewer.dart#4](https://github.com/drydart/model_viewer.dart/issues/4)):

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Model Viewer")),
        body: ModelViewer(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE),
          src: 'https://dashboard.impiattalo.com/storage/app/public/259/bistecca.gltf',
          alt: "Bistecca",
          ar: true,
          autoRotate: true,
          cameraControls: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I can't actually try this with your model URL since the hostname is presumably nonpublic, but the code above does work with other models.

```sh
$ host dashboard.impiattalo.com
Host dashboard.impiattalo.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```